# JQuery Dialog Classes

Tags: jquery

I have started a test on a dialog and I can't seem to get classes to work. I've created this test, can someone please tell me why the classes are not working?   Button classes nor the dialog class.  I tried putting it in the html and in the jQuery with no luck.

```js
$('#myButton').click(function() {
  var msg = $('#myButton').attr("msg");
  $('#dialog').html(msg);
  $('#dialog').dialog({
    title: "Delete Prompt",
    class: "dialogClass",
    autoOpen: true,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "explode",
    modal: true,
    width: "400px",
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [{
        text: "Yes",
        class: 'yesClass',
        click: function() {
          $('#resposneText').html('Yes was clicked');
          $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
      },
      {
        text: "No",
        class: 'noClass',
        click: function() {
          $('#resposneText').html('No was clicked');
          $('#dialog').dialog('close');
        }
      }
    ],
    open: function(event, ui) {
      //setTimeout(function(){
      //    $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      //}, 10000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.ui-dialog,
.ui-dialog-title {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}

.noClass {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

.yesClass {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.ui-dialog
{
  background: blue;
}

.ui-button.yesClass 
{
    background: green;
} 
 
.ui-button.yesClass.ui-state-hover,
.ui-button.yesClass.ui-state-active
{
    background: red;    
}

.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-buttonpane {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="dialog" class="dialogClass" style="display:none;"></div>
<input type="button" id="myButton" msg="Are you sure you want to delete it?" value="Delete This">
<div id="resposneText"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gavinlandon/zkhoja5c/

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to provide working code here on Stack Overflow so that people don't have to go to another site...

Comment: "but the world believes it's required to write in JQuery" - not true at all ;)

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, didn't realize that was there..  I'll do that next time..

Comment: @Adam I'm looking for a new job and every one of them want to know if I write in JQuery, Bootstrap, Angular, and React..    These companies are letting people that know nothing about the libraries to post key words and without those keywords, I can't seem to talk to the actual dev team.   I'm kind of being forced into it if I plan on staying in it.

Comment: [The option is named `classes` according to the docs](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-classes)...

Comment: Changed to classes and still doesn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not so much a javascript problem, more or a CSS problem.

It seems that the class that are being added via jQueryUI have mroe specificity than yours and hence you dont see you changes.

Try this:

```
.ui-button.yesClass {
    background: green;
 } 
.ui-button.yesClass.ui-state-hover,
.ui-button.yesClass.ui-state-active{
    background: red;    
}
```

Hopefully you get the idea and can achieve what you need.

Comment: I have a feeling that once the op really digs into jQuery, he'll become an enthusiast. It happened to a number of us who were once not enthusiastic... Good answer +1

Comment: Thanks brad, that helped with the buttons and yes, I thought it would work by using ui-dialog, for the dialog, but didn't work the same way...   I have a lot to learn about JQuery and I wasn't bashing JQuery, as it's just a library of JavaScript was my point.  I can just the same stuff in JavaScript, but it seems companies don't care so much as long as I can use JQuery.   All about Key words these days.